# Postgres JSON column updating individual keys/attributes with form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am having some trouble updating a rails JSON column in a model.

I have a OrderItem model with an :options column with the postgres json datatype.

I have a form where I am only trying to update two attributes in that JSON column. However, when i run the update action from my controller, it is resetting the entire options column to only the fields in my form rather than just updating the two individual attributes. Is this a bug? I am on Rails 4.2.1 and from what I read this should work, and I can manually update individual attributes in rails console.

In my controller:

```
def update
  @order_item.update(order_item_params)
  respond_with(:update)
end

private 

    def order_item_params
      params.require(:order_item).permit(:product_id, :quantity, options:[:esp, :size])
    end
```

My form:

```
    <%= f.fields_for :options do |option| %>
        <%= option.label :size %>
        <%= option.select :size, options_for_select((5..13), item.options["size"]) %>
        <%= option.select :esp, options_for_select(["yes","no"], item.options["esp"]) %>
    <% end %>
```

When that form is submitted it does not update the individual attributes. It resets the entire json column to only these two attributes

```
Form Data
utf8:✓
_method:patch
order_item[quantity]:2
order_item[options][size]:5
order_item[options][esp]:no
```

In console I can manually update attributes easily...

```
o = OrderItem.last
o.options["esp"] = "yes"
o.save

#PERSISTS!
```

Comment: were you ever able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your full application, but I assume that when you enter only those 2 parameters - it does not perform the same actions you run in the console. When the form is submitted - all your parameters are expected to be accepted, and not only those you added to the form.

In order to prevent that - you can add all your other fields as hidden, and that way to preserve the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually specify how to update your `options` json separately from the rest of the object.

One strategy could be to remove options from the permitted `order_item_params` then do something like this:

```
def update
  @order_item.options.merge!(params[:order_item][:options])
  @order_item.update(order_item_params)
  respond_with(:update)
end
```